# What is the correct notation for an intersection of generalized intersections which share only some predicates?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $Q$ be an index set that indexes two families of sets $\{S_i\}_{i \in Q}$ and $\{F_i\}_{i \in Q}$.
Let $<_A$ and $<_B$ be partial orders on $Q$.

Let $i \in Q$.
Suppose I want to compute
$$
\left(\bigcap \{S_j : (j <_A i) \land (j <_B i)\}\right) \cap
\left(\bigcap \{F_j : (j <_A i) \land (j >_B i)\}\right).
$$

What is a more compact way to represent this?
Maybe the following?
$$
\left(\bigcap_{j <_B i} S_j\right)
\cap
\left(\bigcap_{j >_B i} F_j\right)
: j<_Ai
$$
Also, is it okay to leave out that $j \in Q$ for brevity?

Answer (score 1):

If things like this occurred often enough, I’d probably introduce notation for $\{j\in Q:j<_Xi\}$ and $\{j\in Q:j>_Xi\}$ for any relation $<_X$ that might appear, perhaps $\downarrow_Xi$ and $\uparrow_Xi$. Then I’d write it

$$\bigcap_{j\in\downarrow_Ai\cap\downarrow_Bi}S_j\cap\bigcap_{j\in\downarrow_Ai\cap\uparrow_Bi}F_j\,.$$

I definitely would not leave that $j<_Ai$ hanging as you have done; without introducing new notation I’d make it

$$\bigcap_{\substack{j<_Ai\\j<_Bi}}S_j\cap\bigcap_{\substack{j<_Ai\\j>_Bi}}F_j\,.$$

Comment: I like your second solution. But, how does one know whether $\substack{j<_Ai\\j<_Bi}$ corresponds to $j <_B i \land j <_A i$ or $j <_B i \lor j <_A i$?

Comment: Also, in your first solution, do you know how to decrease the horizontal spacing?

Comment: @cisprague: It’s a matter of convention: that notation is always to be interpreted as the conjunction of the conditions. If you wanted the disjunction, the first intersection would be replaced by $$\bigcap_{j<_Ai}S_j\cap\bigcap_{j<_Bi}S_j\,,$$ for instance. As to the spacing, do you mean something like this? $$\bigcap_{\substack{j<_Ai\\j<_Bi}}\!\!S_j\cap\bigcap_{\substack{j<_Ai\\j>_Bi}}\!\!F_j$$ If you right click on that and Show Math As TeX Commands, you can see what I did: I inserted `\!\!` before $S_j$ and $F_j$.